# ReactRedux I want to update state but always getting "TypeError:Can’t read property 'address' of undefined" same code work fine to update other state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a CRUD app where I have to update my address and PIN code. I am trying to update the address with fetched data using Redux, but always getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined" I don't know what wrong with the code because same code updates the `City` field.

**EditLocation.js**

```
 const EditLocation = ({
  location: { location, loading },
  editLocation,
  getCurrentLocation,
  history,
  match
}) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    address: "",
    pinCode: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentLocation(match.params.id);

    setFormData({
      address: loading || !location.address ? "" : location.address, // i am getting error here code cant define location.adress
      pinCode: loading || !location.pinCode ? "" : location.pinCode
    });
  }, [loading, getCurrentLocation]);

  const onChangeHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    editLocation(formData, history, match.params.id);
  };
   return (
<div>
</div>
)}
EditLocation.propTypes = {
  editLocation: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getCurrentLocation: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  location: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  location: state.location
});

// alert(JSON.stringify(location.address));

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { editLocation, getCurrentLocation }
)(withRouter(EditLocation));
```

**LocationAction.js**

```
// Get current location
export const getCurrentLocation = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/location/${id}`);
    console.log(res.data.data.address);

    dispatch({
      type: types.GET_LOCATION,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: types.LOCATION_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

**locationReducer.js**

```
import * as types from "../../_actions/types";

const initialState = {
  location: null,
  locations: [],
  error: {},
  filtered: null,
  loading: true
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case types.GET_LOCATION:
      return {
        ...state,
        location: payload,
        loading: false
      };
default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

However when I use Postman it works fine and also the  `console.log(res.data.data.address);` in locationAction.js shows the fetched data but when I click on update button it show the TypeError.
I repeated the same code and it is working fine when I want to update the `City` field.

Comment: How you render your data, I do not see these lines of code, I think the error is on the first load of the page (not the API), you read the data from `location` props when it is not initialized.

Comment: Sir. current location is rendered through useEffect in editlocation.js file. as the edit page is called it set the fetched data into the input field but in  b/w the process it show the Type Error